# Import Protobuf generated classes using Gradle in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am having trouble importing Protobuf generated classes using Gradle.

This is how my project tree looks like:

[image: Project tree:]

I've tried marking the packages as Source, I have tried all possible combinations of imports:

```
import generated.main.grpc.GreeterGrpc;
import main.java.HelloRequest;
import java.*;
import HelloRequest;
```

None of them works. Here is my build.gradle:

```
group 'andu'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.0.0-pre2'
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.0.0'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.0.0-pre2'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.3.0'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.3.0'
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.3.0'
}



sourceSets {
    main {
        proto {
            srcDir 'src/main/proto'
        }
        java {
            srcDirs =  ['src/main/java', 'generated/main/java']
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.2.0"
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.3.0'
        }
    }

    generateProtoTasks.generatedFilesBaseDir = 'generated'

    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {}
        }
    }
}
```

Before I added

```
generateProtoTasks.generatedFilesBaseDir = 'generated'
```

all of my generated classes would be added to build/generated/main/java

Answer (score 7):

from : https://medium.com/@DivyaJaisawal/generate-java-code-from-proto-file-using-gradle-1fb9fe64e046

The Protobuf plugin assumes Protobuf files (*.proto) are organized in the same way as Java source files, in sourceSets. The Protobuf files of a sourceSet are compiled in a single protoc run, and the generated files are added to the input of the Java compilation run of that sourceSet ().

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc'
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/java'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It may be a little different since I did this in an Android project, but what worked for me was adding `classpath "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.1"` in my root build.gradle and the following in the apps build.gradle.

Also don't forget to run a gradle build as only running won't generate the classes automatically unless you have the `build project automatically` [option](https://www.mkyong.com/intellij/intellij-idea-how-to-build-project-automatically/) selected in compiler options.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

protobuf {
    generatedFilesBaseDir = "$projectDir/generated"
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0'
    }
    plugins {
        javalite {
            artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0"
        }
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.0.3'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java
            }
            task.plugins {
                grpc {}
            }
        }
    }
}

//Protobuf
compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.0'
compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.0.0'

//GRPC
compile('io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.1.1') {
    exclude module: 'jsr305'
}
compile('io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.1.1') {
    exclude module: 'jsr305'
}
compile('io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.1.1') {
    exclude module: 'jsr305'
}
```

I've also made two basic but working examples using gRPC that may be able to help. [Example Java project](https://github.com/spik3r/grpc) using Maven (if you're open to switching to Maven). And a basic [Example Android project](https://github.com/spik3r/grpcDroid) using gradle although there are minor differences (I'm using java-lite and okhttp instead of netty).

Answer (score 3):

I had same issues in intellij while in sbt everything worked just fine, its just problem of higlightning it in IDE. I had to go to 'Project structure'->'Modules'->click on 'root'-> 'Depencencies'->'+' sign at the bottom-> Jars or directories -> add your generated dir as dependency.

Comment: By 'root' do you mean "the root of the project". In my case it was named something else.

Comment: This only this worked for me , thanks a ton

Answer (score -2):

If you want to generate for java, you have to mention a package name in your proto file like this:

```
option java_package = "com.example";
```

Do that and generate again.

Now import like this:

```
`import com.example.HelloRequest;`
```

Comment: This does not solve the porblem. I still cannot import the generated files in main/src/java

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, this did solve it for me. My generated .java had no package, after defining the java_package in the .proto file then the .java had a package defined and immediately intelliJ was able to import it.

I guess there are 2 different issues regarding importing a protobuff generated class. This answerd solved my issue.