# Unable to import generated classes using wildcard in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ for a gradle project.
The project structure looks like this:

```
root
├── generated_src [main] (generated sources root)
├── generated_testSrc [tests] (generated test sources root)
├── out
│   └── production
│       ├── classes
│       └── resources
└── src
    └── main
        └── java (sources root)
```

IntelliJ created 3 modules based on the gradle configuration, which look like this:

```
my_project (containing everything, but nothing marked as Sources)
my_project_main (containing generated_src, marked as Sources)
my_project_test (containing generated_testSrc, marked as Tests)
```

The Annotation processor is used to generate classes in the generated_src folder, resulting in classes which look like this:

```
generated_src [main] (generated sources root)
└── path.to.entities
    └── MyEntity_.java
out
└── production
    └── classes
         └── path.to.entities
              └── MyEntity.java
```

All usages of generated classes are imported using the wildcard syntax. But it seems that IntelliJ thinks that the imports refer to the package from *out/production/classes* folder and the generated class is not imported. It gives me the option to import it and generates:

```
import path.to.entities.*;
import path.to.entities.MyEntity_; <--WARNING: not used, remove?
```

After importing the generated class, it shows the import as not used, because the package is already imported with the wildcard syntax. If I remove the second import I get back to the original state where the *MyEntity_* is not imported.

I have tried:

- importhing everything without the wildcard syntax. Works but violates team code style
- marking *my_project_main* as dependency for module *my_project*, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44130093/2342529). Problem remains

How can I correctly set up my project in order for the generated classes to be imported correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by updating the following settings for the Annotation Processor

- Production sources directory: "**../generated_src**"
- Test sources directory: "**../generated_testSrc**"